# Make changes to database in Rails without having to reset the whole thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, lightbox, colorbox

I'm new to Rails and coding, so this may be a very basic question...

This evening I was working on an app and changed the image uploader so that it saves two different sizes of images to the database - one smaller to show on the page, and one larger version for using in a lightbox (colorbox).

The issue I ran into was that users already existed in the database both in development and in production. Luckily, I created these users using the Faker gem, and in production it was just me posting things to check out how it looks in production.

So, for images that were already in the database, they were only saved as the smaller version thereby making it so that the lightbox displays a broken image (because the larger version doesn't exist).

Because I could do so without losing anything important, I reset the database and in development I ran the Faker rake again, and in production I just signed back up and uploaded some of my own photos over again. (I am pretty much absolutely positive this is not best practices... but I am really just getting into the second month of learning...)

My question is this: Is there a way to redo the database so that those images that were originally in there get to stay, and are just re-saved to the database with both versions.

Or alternatively, is there a way to need only one version of the image saved and the lightbox/colorbox can manipulate the original size image to render in the size I want?
For example, maybe it would be that when the user uploads an image, the image saves to the database in the larger version and then for the "thumbnail" I code it so that it just shrinks the photo down to the size I want displayed on the page??

For reference, here is a link to the Heroku deployment of the app:

http://desolate-waters-6166.herokuapp.com/

I am using this app as my own sample app for trying out different things and learning how to do things on something without much consequence.

Thanks in advance! Let me know if I need to provide more info. I can also link the github repository for this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, the site looks pretty cool. To answer your question, I don't there is an easy way, nor worth the task, of taking all your user's images and attempting to transform them into high quality. I think the best option would be to add a column for high res thumbnails, and make sure thumbnails get saved as high res going forward. I do believe, to answer your second question, if you store a high quality image, then shrinking it will not hurt the quality, only going beyond the size of the resolution, if that makes sense. So maybe deprecate storing low quality images, and just store them high res going forward.

Comment: Awesome - sounds like a great solution and it makes sense to me. Thank you for the direction and answering so quickly.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the compliment too - the encouragement helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). It uses ImageMagick for image resizing and stores the image location in the database (instead of the image itself). This way you can store the image files at cheaper of free locations , like S3 of Amazon. The other advantage is size versioning, which is made very smooth.